# How dynamoDB queries work on DateTimeString

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table which items are like

```
Ordered      order_date             created_at                          details 
123           2023-05-10 10:04:05   Date#2023-05-10T00:00:00             {}
32132         2023-05-11 11:04:05   Date#2023-05-101T00:00:00            {}
```

orderId is **partition_key** and order_date/created_at is **sort_key** of table.

As mentioned in dynamoDB doc, dynamoDB support only ISO format date string for date Time queries. order_date in the above format is not ISO format.

1. how will dynamoDB behave if i do between query on order_date (sort_key) here.
2. how will dynamoDB behave if i do between query on created_at (compound sort_key) here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You said that order_date/created_at is the sort key. Are you saying that the sort key, which must be a single attribute, is actually a composite of these two values?

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB stores dates as string values, so its best to think of them as just strings. It sorts strings [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order), so as long as your comparisons are lexicographically correct it will work.

Furthermore, you can only have 1 sort key on a table, not two. If you want to sort on a non-key field you need to use a [FilterExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression)